# IF Else IF statement in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello below my code is working fine.

When `A1` Cell is updated with `File1` it will open a `File1` link.

but i need to add more `else if statement` to get open different link.
Example :

if `A1` is updated with `File2` it will open `File2` link

if `A1` is updated with `File3` it will open `File3` link

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Sheet1" || range.getA1Notation() != "A1" || range.getValue() != "File1") return;
  const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  const html = `<script>window.open('${url}', '_blank');google.script.host.close();</script>`;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), "File1");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could organise it so the first condition doesn't check if the value isn't File1 and add three else if with its code blocks, and a final else condition to return if the value doesn't match those three files:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Sheet1" || range.getA1Notation() != "A1") return;
  else if (range.getValue() == "File1"){
   first code block}
  else if (range.getValue() == "File2"){
   Second code block}
  else if (range.getValue() == "File3"){
   Third code block}
  else return


}
```